# pipe() function in Spark, from Java to C++, with not String data

Tags: java, c++, apache-spark

I'm trying to pipe data from Spark (app written in Java) to a C++ executable. 
My RDD are like : `JavaRDD<CustomMatrix>`, where `CustomMatrix` implements `Serializable`. It is made up of metadata (int, long, String ...) and a `short[][]`. 
Other transformations, like map/flatMap/... , work well.

I would like to send the array (`short[][]`) to a C++ program, to perform some transformations, and get back the modified array.

I used pipe function for piping data as String to a C++ exec. But now I have to serialize my data and send it to the C++ exec. Does anybody have any idea how this should be effectively handled?